# Laravel auth:user() relationship doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, relationship

I have two relationships in my user model:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}

public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class, 'currency_id');
}
```

If I try to use in controller role relationship it works, but currency relationship brings NULL with dd($user)

```
$user = Auth::user()->currency;
$user = Auth::user()->role;
```

[image: dd($user)]

It has to be something with AUTH. Thank you for your help.

full User Model:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Hash;

/**
* Class User
*
* @package App
* @property string $name
* @property string $email
* @property string $password
* @property string $role
* @property string $remember_token
*/
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token', 
'role_id', 'currency_id'];



/**
 * Hash password
 * @param $input
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($input)
{
    if ($input)
        $this->attributes['password'] = app('hash')-
>needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;
}


/**
 * Set to null if empty
 * @param $input
 */
public function setRoleIdAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['role_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
}

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}

public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class, 'currency_id');
}

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
   $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token));
}
}
```

my currency model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Traits\FilterByUser;

/**
 * Class Currency
 *
 * @package App
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $symbol
 * @property string $money_format
 * @property string $created_by
*/
class Currency extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes, FilterByUser;

protected $fillable = ['title', 'symbol', 'money_format', 
'created_by_id'];



/**
 * Set to null if empty
 * @param $input
 */
public function setCreatedByIdAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['created_by_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
}

public function created_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by_id');
}

}
```

Comment: Are you giving to relation ship in role or currency model or not ? Please check.

Comment: Do you have `currency` and/or `currency_id` in the `users` table?

Comment: currency_id in users table

Comment: @Darius the relationship you use is correct. Please show results of `dd(auth()->user())`. Unfold all arrays in the results.

Comment: added dd(auth()->user())

Comment: Doest it works using `User::with('role','currency')->find(Auth::id())`

Comment: @Darius everything looks fine. Please show full `User` model. Also, make sure you have currency with `ID = 3` in the `currencies` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `currency_id` an integer instead of string:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('currency_id');
```

Comment: It doesnt matter. if that is the problem `role` relation should work and it doesnt

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz `role_id` is integer.

Comment: but it doesnt work neither so i dont think that being an string is the real problem

Comment: i think he is right. still checking and i will let you know soon.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz OP says "If I try to use in controller role relationship it works"

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin My bad, didnt read that. Your answer must be right then

Comment: sorry, still have same problem.

Comment: if i use with tinker just like: $user=\App\User::find(5) and then $user->currency it works well, but with auth doesnt work...

Comment: @Darius did you rerun Tinker after you've made these changes? Also, please show the `Currency` model and results for `dd(Currency::find(3))`

Comment: @Darius if `\App\User::find(5)->currency` works then `auth()->user()->currency` will work too. Rerun Tinker.

Comment: dd(Currency::find(3)); bring NULL

Comment: @Darius well, that's the problem. There is no currency with ID = 3 and you've said `\App\User::find(5)->currency` works. Which can't work if there is no currency with ID = 3.

Comment: auth()->user()->currency
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1

Comment: @Darius that's because the user is not logged in. Do `auth()->loginUsingId(5)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163873/discussion-between-darius-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 1):

did u mean eager loading?
add with property in user model

```
protected $with = ['role','currency'];
```